# Get created item's ID created using NewForm.aspx in modal dialog

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am creating a new item using NewForm.aspx opened using SP showModalDialog.
How can I get the ID of created item after form is saved?

I need to get the ID to do some processing.

Comment: See [1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111148/get-list-item-id-from-newform-aspx) & [2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100160/pass-newitem-id-to-callback-function-from-newitem-form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this using [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/)

```
var lastID = $().SPServices.SPGetLastItemId({
    listName:'List 1'
});
```

this will get last inserted item's id which was created by same user.

**List 1** is list's name

Answer (score 1):

You can try running a SP2013 REST api and

> get top 1 item while they are sorted by Created date in descending
>   order

once your model dialog saves data in the list. Please refer this:

```
 _api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('your_List_title')/items?$top=1&$select=ID&$orderby=Created desc
```

Comment: We can consider using CreatedBy id, so in case of multi user environment you will get the last inserted by same user

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the out of the box modal as a template and utilize the "dialogReturnValueCallback".

```
// initialize your app name and guid
var appListName= 'YOUR LIST NAME';
var appListGuid = 'YOUR LIST GUID';

// onclick attribute to place if you have a custom button
onclick="displayCustomModalApp(\''+_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+'/Lists/'+appListName+'/NewForm.aspx?&IsDlg=1\')"

// custom modal using modified SharePoint OOB modal method
function displayCustomModalApp(mUrl, width, height, title) {    
    var options = {
        url: mUrl,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        title: title,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult){
            // only reset page if item is saved, do nothing if cancelled or closed
            if(dialogResult){
                // run the function to get last item Id when the dialog closes
                retrieveLastItemID();
            }
        }
    };
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}

// function to retrieve the last created item Id from current logged in user
function retrieveLastItemID() {

    // filter by current author id and order by 'Id desc' to get the latest
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var fullUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'"+appListGuid+"')/items?$select=Id&$filter=Author/Id eq '"+_spPageContextInfo.userId+"'&$orderby=Id desc&$top=1";

    $.ajax({
        url: fullUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var lastId = data.d.results[0].Id;
            // DO STUFF!
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```